# Runtime exception : Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3, geocoder

I tried to get an address from a pointed location on google maps and get this error :

> Blockquote
>   FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                     Process: elder.msu.testlocationapp, PID: 23559
>                     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{elder.msu.testlocationapp/elder.msu.testlocationapp.MapsActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'double com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng.latitude' on a null object reference
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2366)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2515)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:154)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1379)
>                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5571)
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:745)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:635)
>                      Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'double com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng.latitude' on a null object reference
>                         at elder.msu.testlocationapp.MapsActivity.(MapsActivity.java:32)
>                         at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
>                         at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1068)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2356)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2515) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:154) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1379) 
>                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5571) 
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:745) 
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:635)

I every necessary thing in my manifest.
Here is my code for the map activity

```
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng) {
            markerOptions.position(latLng);
            markerOptions.title(latLng.latitude + " : " + latLng.longitude);
            mMap.clear();
            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
            mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
        }
    });

private void getAddress(){

    Geocoder geocoder;
    final List<Address> addresses;
    geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
    try{
        addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude,longitude,1);

        if (addresses!=null && addresses.size() > 0){
            address = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
            city = addresses.get(0).getLocality();
        }

    }catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Cannot get data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }


    btnOK.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            getAddress();
            confirmData(address, city);

        }
    });


}

private void confirmData(String address, String city) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    intent.putExtra("data", bundle);
    intent.putExtra("address", address);
    intent.putExtra("city", city);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To stop this error simply wrap the map click listener code.

```
if (latLng != null) {
    markerOptions.position(latLng);
    markerOptions.title(latLng.latitude + " : " + latLng.longitude);
    mMap.clear();
    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
    mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
}
```

As for why it is giving a null value, I am not sure. Does this occur during onCreate when the activity first starts?

Comment: it still crash when I start the maps activity